# Excluding certain folders from bundling in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, metro-bundler

So I have certain folders that I want to exclude from my production build. I came across this option in metro bundler documentation [blocklist](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#blocklist) which takes a list of regular expression matching the folders to exclude. My issue is that I want to exclude certain folders based on a key in my env file which is different for different environments. I am passing my environment file to the run-ios script as shown

> ENVFILE=.env.nonprod react-native run-ios

I want to know if I can read this file in metro.config.js file so that based on the env variable value I can decide if it the folder needs to be excluded or not.